# IE9 ignoring chunks of my style sheets (Not the 4096 selector limit)

Tags: css, internet-explorer-9

I'm using SASS and Foundation 4 on a project.  In IE9 the css just gets ignored about half way through the generated css file.  I've tried compressing the file and I get the same results. Anyone ever heard of another random limit that IE9 has besides the 4096 selector limit?

Uncompressed and with comments the css file is 795KB.  IE9 ignores everything after 483KB.

Compressed the css file is 415KB. IE9 ignores everything after 223KB.  It does read/interpret about  20 more selectors when the file is compressed.

The uncompressed version can be seen here: https://gist.github.com/benlwilliams/7930177

Comment: Are you sure you don't have an error in the CSS that IE chokes on?

Comment: Are you able to post the CSS code somewhere so we can have a look? Does it validate (or get as close to validation as you can get with vendor prefixes etc)? Are there any strange characters in there (e.g. unicode zero-width spaces or something)?

Comment: I am not 100% sure, but where IE9 stops reading, I can find nothing wrong.

Comment: @OllyHodgson I updated the question with a link to the css file. I did run it through a validator and got a number of errors.  But something was strange in that the line it said the error occurred didn't actually match up with the content of the css file at that line number.  I used this validator: http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator

Comment: @Ben Odd. That might indicate a parse error. Do all of your `{` and `}` match up? Are you able to post the file anywhere?

Comment: @OllyHodgson Also, I don't think it's a validation issue since it chokes on an area that isn't that all controversial: `.baseicon-pictures:before { content: "\e137"; }` Dozens of similar rules exist before and after this in the style sheet.

Comment: @OllyHodgson File posted here: https://gist.github.com/benlwilliams/7930177

Comment: @Ben There's a broken selector on line 22165 (`:note` should be `:not`). The CSS validator is choking on all the IE7 hacks (`*whatever`) which makes things tricky to read. Also, negative padding in places like `.padding-pull-up-small` doesn't make any sense - probably won't do anything. Nothing *too* out of the ordinary though. I wonder if it's a character encoding issue?

Comment: There's also a couple of places where you've declared `content: "";` twice in one selector. Probably not the problem though. I wonder if `content: " ╗";` might be causing an issue?

Comment: @OllyHodgson I don't remember using a content: " ╗";  Unless Stack overflow is somehow changing that character.  I'll look for that.  But still, like you said, nothing that should keep it from being read.  The negative padding is from a mixin that uses margins too. I probably should put some if/else in there to skip the negative padding.

Comment: The ╗ is not caused by StackOverflow; maybe by Github; it's at line 10527. If there's an encoding mismatch, perhaps that could have caused a \x1A byte to occur in the CSS. But you said the validator was wrong about the line numbers? which line numbers? I checked a few and they all matched the listing at Github...

Comment: Yeah, I didn't get the line-number mismatches either. This sounds more and more like a weird character encoding issue.

Comment: @OllyHodgson I removed the strange ` ╗ ` character, which was actually a ` » ` character in my .scss file. So I'll start down the character encoding trail now.

Comment: @MrLister The line mismatch occurred really far down in the error list.  Sometimes it would say a line number and have what was wrong listed next to it, but when I looked at the style sheet at that line, it was not the right place.  I could have been reading the error chart wrong though.  I don't always understand what it's trying to tell me with some of those obscure errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran your posted CSS through a [CSS selector counter](http://snippet.bevey.com/css/selectorCount.php).

It returns 9,855 selectors.

Comment: Yep, it was too many selectors after all.  When I was running a script to count the selectors I must have not compared it to a working browser.  I only ran it in IE9 which was ignoring the extra styles and so was apparently also causing JS to miss-count them when running a script in console.